# how to upgrade Composer to v2?

Tags: composer

I am trying to upgrade composer to Composer2 (from Composer1).

```
richb201@richb201-XPS-13-9370:/opt/docker-substantiator2/app/vendor/sendpulse-rest-api-php-master/src$ composer selfupdate
Updating to version 2.0.13 (stable channel).
   Downloading (100%)         

                                                                                                        
  [ErrorException]                                                                                      
  rename(/home/richb201/.cache/composer/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?